# How to set up virtualization servers? 

Tags: server, virtualization

I have 2 pcs that I wish to setup as virtualisation servers. One has an I7 cpu and another one that doesn't support hardware virtualisation. Can someone give me instructions to configure it? If I can have a web ui to control the virtualisation it would be great. These server will only be used for virtualisation so multiple desktop could be setup and used from the network.

Comment: I was trying to follow the following instructions [link](http://www.howtoforge.com/virtualization-with-kvm-on-ubuntu-11.10) but some items were no longer available and got lost. During the installation I selected the virtualsation node.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be the best guide for KVM:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM

Comment: How can I control the KVM with web ui such as with ISPConfig. Only virtualsation, because most tutorials are with mail etc